# Double strings in groovy script

Tags: file, groovy, io, soapui

I'm using soapUI groovy script to write rest response and request to file.
i'm using the next code:

```
def snapShotDirTarget = context.expand( '${#Project#SnapShotDirTarget}' )
def fileDir = new File(snapShotDirTarget);
if(!fileDir .exists()) {
     fileDir .mkdirs();
} 

def currentDate = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
def fileName =  "test "+currentDate+" .txt"
def resultsFile= new File(fileDir ,fileName );  //generate file by test name and test suite

if(!resultsFile.exists()) {


    resultsFile.append("Test"+currentDate+'\n' );    //Test suite Name as header

}


resultsFile.append("Post URL:EXAMPLE"'\n' );
```

my out put:

> Test2014-08-12 10-43-35
>
> Post URL:EXAMPLE
> Post URL:EXAMPLE

I don't know why it prints the text out of the if, twice.

Comment: Works as expected for me in 2.3.4 after fixing the bug in your EXAMPLE string

Comment: I'm guessing you ran it twice in the same second, as that would append the last line twice to the same file.